# R - Fastest way to loop subsets and get outputs using datatables (calculating monthly measures)

Tags: r, performance, loops, dataframe, subset

I have a problem where I am hoping to calculate some monthly measures for different entities but the code I am currently using appears to be very slow. I am wondering if perhaps you may know of a better solution.

A simplified version of my dataset is below. The problem is that one of datasets contains some 6m individual daily observations and my current method appears to be very slow.

```
  date     event  id return
2000-07-06     2  1   0.1
2000-07-07     1  1   0.2
2000-07-09     0  1   0.6
2000-07-10     0  1   0.4
2000-07-15     2  1   0.7
2000-07-16     1  1   0.3
2000-07-20     0  1   0.1
2000-07-21     1  1   0.2
2000-07-06     1  2   0.3
2000-07-07     2  2   0.4
2000-07-15     0  2   0.6
2000-07-16     0  2   0.8
2000-07-17     2  2   0.9
2000-07-18     1  2   0.1
```

To calculate these measures I am running code that looks like the following:

```
for (j in 1:length(list.of.ids)) {
  for (i in 1:(number.of.months) {
    temp <- subset(data, data$date < FirstDayMonth[i+1] & data$date >= FirstDayMonth[i] & data$id == list.of.ids[j])
    total[i,j+1] <- sum(temp$return, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Note: total[,] is a matrix with a time column and one column for each id and the number of rows equals every month in the dataset. I am hoping to have a matrix that stores all my monthly measures for ids and months. This loop allows me to calculate the monthly sum of returns by id and then store it in that matrix.

Again, the code above allows me to subset on a month period (by restricting my observations to be between the first day of two consecutive months) and on ids. The problem is, for my larger datasets this is very slow.

Are there any improvements to the code that will allow me to get my desired output faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improvements that should yield speedup:

```
for (j in 1:length(list.of.ids)) {
  id1 <- data$id == list.of.ids[j]
  # outside 2nd loop so no redundant operations wont be made
  for (i in 1:(number.of.months)) {
    id2 <- data$date < FirstDayMonth[i+1] & data$date >= FirstDayMonth[i]
    total[i, j+1] <- sum(data$return[id1 & id2], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

(probably big improvements, as we do not need to create new `data.frame` object each time, we just get indexes for which elements we need to calculate the sum)

But I would use `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[, ym := format(date, '%Y-%m')]
res <- data[, sum(return, na.rm = T), keyby = .(ym, id)]
res
#         ym id  V1
# 1: 2000-07  1 2.6
# 2: 2000-07  2 3.1
```

if needed the end result can be transformed to matrix:

```
m <- matrix(res$V1, nrow = length(unique(res$ym)))
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  2.6  3.1
```

#### Update:

Faster version:

```
setDT(data) # converts data to data.table
x <- data[, .(date = unique(date))][, .(date, ym = format(date, '%Y-%m'))]
data[x, ym := i.ym, on = 'date']
res <- data[, sum(return, na.rm = T), keyby = .(ym, id)]
res
```

(`format(date, '%Y-%m')` is slow, so we take only unique dates and calculate `ym` for them, then merge that to data. This should be quite faster, if you have lots of duplicated dates.)

#### Update 2:

Conversion to matrix can be obtained with:

```
resdt <- dcast(res, ym ~ id, value.var = 'V1') # change data structure
resdt[1:2, 1:3]
#         ym        1        2
# 1: 2000-01 6.824182 2.535805
# 2: 2000-02 3.825659 6.769578
resdt[, ym := NULL] # delets ym
setcolorder(resdt, neworder = list.of.ids) # reorder columns
m <- as.matrix(resdt)
m[1:2, 1:2]
#             1        2         3
# [1,] 6.824182 2.535805 -1.193692
# [2,] 3.825659 6.769578 -1.117223
```

Comment: Hi! This looks really good. I was planning on trying to use datatables to do it. But I was unsure how to store the outputs / save them as a separate output. Would like to hear more about this. And thank you!

Comment: @Rnovice see my edit. I am interested if the first approach gives your desired speed improvement, as it is much simpler to incorporate in your existing code.

Comment: I'll give it a go now!

Comment: I've run the code for 5 ids. And the results are below. I used the system.time command.   

`user  system elapsed 
 49.855  19.579  69.979`

Again, the problem is that I have 855ids so I am still not sure if this is feasible given what I want to do. I am also calculating multiple monthly measures so I would need to speed this process up immensely to be able to finish within a reasonable timeframe.

Comment: The data table method appears to be the fastest/

Comment: Great! This looks really good. Thank you very much. I also have a question about how to get this into the matrix form I want. The reason I am so fussy about this matrix method is that I have some additional code later that hinges on the format. In particular, I was hoping to have the variables stored in columns that are the same order as my id list. (eg. col 1 corresponds to id[1] in my list)

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate`. The year-month variable `ym` we can create with the `substr`ing of the first to the seventh character of the date column.

```
m <- with(dat, aggregate(list(return=return),
                         by=list(ym=substr(date, 1, 7), id=id), sum))
m
#        ym id return
# 1 2000-07  1    2.6
# 2 2000-07  2    3.1
```

Or `tapply`.

```
m <- with(dat, tapply(return, list(ym=substr(date, 1, 7), id=id), sum))
m
#          id
# ym          1   2
#   2000-07 2.6 3.1
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(date = c("2000-07-06", "2000-07-07", "2000-07-09", 
"2000-07-10", "2000-07-15", "2000-07-16", "2000-07-20", "2000-07-21", 
"2000-07-06", "2000-07-07", "2000-07-15", "2000-07-16", "2000-07-17", 
"2000-07-18"), event = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L), id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), return = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, -14L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi! Are you using the ym variable as created by minem? I am guessing you are but just want to check

Comment: @Rnovice Actually not, it's created with `substr(dat$date, 1, 7)`, i.e. first to seventh character of the dates.

Comment: Great! And how would I get it nicely into a matrix for storage? Sorry, I just want to understand the full process.

Comment: @Rnovice What do you mean by a matrix for storage, could you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

This should be considerably faster:

```
for(i in 1:length(number.of.months)) {
  inds <- dat$date < FirstDayMonth[i+1] & dat$date >= FirstDayMonth[i]
  total[i,] <- rowsum(dat$result[inds], dat$id[inds], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Hi! When I try and run your code it returns the below error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, , value = c(3, 6, 3, 4, 1, 14, 16,  : 
  replacement has 597 items, need 856

I suspect it is because I don't have a full 856 ids throughout the whole time period.

Also, the first column I was hoping to be my date column. Not sure if this is covered in your code.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a sample of your actual datasets? It is a bit hard to know how everything looks on your side. i.e. you use things like `FirstDayOfMonth` in your code, but they are not provided in the question.